# Dynamically adding a 3 tier movieclip to stage then populate it

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

What I am trying to do is add say 20 jpgs labelled 1-20 individually inside movieClips [ sReel ] , then add the movieClips to movieClip [ aReel ] and duplicate movieClip [ aReel ] into movieClip [ mReel ] so I can have a horizontal scrolling movieClip.

I can do all manually no problem but doing it automatically is not so easy :(

Just need how to stack the mocieClips correctly as know how to do rest oc code Thanks..

```
var movie_Number:Array = new Array();
var movie_Title: Array = new Array();
var movie_Director: Array = new Array();
var movie_Star: Array = new Array();
var movie_Duration: Array = new Array();
var movie_Genre: Array = new Array();
var movie_Year: Array = new Array();
var movie_Rating: Array = new Array();
var movie_Comment: Array = new Array();


var mReel:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var aReel:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var bReel:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var sReel:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
var ldr:Loader;

newReelMask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
mReel.cacheAsBitmap = true;
mReel.mask = newReelMask;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(), xmlData:XML;
var movieNum:Number;
var xReel = 0;

mReel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onStop);
mReel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onStart);

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

init();

makeSmallReel();
aReel.x = 0;
aReel.y = 0;
mReel.addChild(aReel);

addChild(mReel);



function init():void
{
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("movieInfo.xml"));
}

function LoadXML(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    var movieTitle:XMLList = xmlData..title;
    var movieDirector:XMLList = xmlData..director;
    var movieStar:XMLList = xmlData..star;
    var movieDuration:XMLList = xmlData..duration;
    var movieGenre:XMLList = xmlData..genre;
    var movieYear:XMLList = xmlData..year;
    var movieRating:XMLList = xmlData..rating;
    var movieComment:XMLList = xmlData..comment;
    var len: int = xmlData.movie.length();
    var i:int = 0;
    for (i; i < len; i++)
        {
            movie_Number.push(i);
            movie_Title.push(movieTitle[i]);
            movie_Director.push(movieDirector[i]);
            movie_Star.push(movieStar[i]);
            movie_Duration.push(movieDuration[i]);
            movie_Genre.push(movieGenre[i]);
            movie_Year.push(movieYear[i]);
            movie_Rating.push(movieRating[i]);
            movie_Comment.push(movieComment[i]);
        }
}

function makeSmallReel():void
{
    var i:int = 1;
    for (i; i < 11; i++)
    {
    ldr = new Loader();
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ldr_complete);
    ldr.load(new URLRequest("images/thumb/"+i+".jpg"));
    }
}
function ldr_complete(e:Event):void 
{
    sReel.x = xReel;
    sReel.addChild(ldr);
    xReel = xReel + e.target.width;
    aReel.addChild(sReel);
}

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (mReel.x <= -(aReel.width))
        {
        mReel.x = 0;
        }
    mReel.x -= 1;
}

function onStop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimer.stop();
}

function onStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You 're adding always the same loader(ldr is a class-var) to your container.
At loading you have to create a ldr vor each picture. And add this to your container in your complete-handler. (it's `e.target` in your complete-handler)

BTW: You don't need a MovieCLip. A Sprite is enought, 'cause semms, you never need the timeline of a movieclip, which is the difference between MovieClip and Sprite ( and the overhead).